# XML Validation - node1 or node2

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm new in XSD. I would need an XSD-Schema that include a simple "OR-Section". As example: node1 or node2 can only be choose, not both.

```
<root>
  <node1/>
     <-- OR, only one can used -->
  <node2/>
</root>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it would be very nice. :)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `xs:choice` structure:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="node1" type="typeOfNode1" />
    <xs:element name="node2" type="typeOfNode2" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```